# While loop to add data for pivot

Tags: t-sql, while-loop, pivot, pivot-table

Currently i have a requirement which needs a table to look like this:

```
Instrument  Long  Short  2013  2014  2015  2016  2017  2018  2019   2020  2021  2022 ....    
Fixed       41    41     35    35    35    35    35    35    35     53    25    25
Index       16    16     22    22    22    32    12    12    12     12    12    12
Credits     29    29     41    16    16    16    16    16    16     16    16    16
Short term  12    12     5     5     5     5     5     5     5      5     5     17
```

My worktable looks like the following:

```
Instrument  Long  Short  Annual Coupon  Maturity Date  Instrument ID
Fixed       10    10     10             01/01/2025     1   
Index       5     5      10             10/05/2016     2
Credits     15    15     16             25/06/2020     3
Short term  12    12     5              31/10/2022     4
Fixed       13    13     15             31/03/2030     5
Fixed       18    18     10             31/01/2019     6
Credits     14    14     11             31/12/2013     7
Index       11    11     12             31/10/2040     8
..... etc
```

So basically the long and the short in the pivot should be the sum of each distinct instrument ID.  And then for each year i need to take the sum of each Annual Coupon until the maturity date year where the long and the coupon rate are added together.

My thinking was that i had to create a while loop which would populate a table with a record for each year for each instrument until the maturity date, so that i could then pivot using an sql pivot some how.  Does this seem feasible?  Any other ideas on the best way of doing this, particularly i might need help on the while loop?

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind the `long`/`short` totals in the desired result? And why does `2016` for `Fixed` have a value of `110`?

Comment: long short is just the value for the reporting period for each instrument.  The two tables above are not using the same data, i just randomly made it up.

Comment: Can you edit the desired result to have it match your sample data?  It is difficult to determine the logic if the data/result don't match.

Comment: apologies, i've edited now

Answer (score 0):

The following solution uses a numbers table to unfold ranges in your table, performs some special processing on some of the data columns in the unfolded set, and finally pivots the results:

```
WITH unfolded AS (
  SELECT
    t.Instrument,
    Long      = SUM(z.Long ) OVER (PARTITION BY Instrument),
    Short     = SUM(z.Short) OVER (PARTITION BY Instrument),
    Year      = y.Number,
    YearValue = t.AnnualCoupon + z.Long + z.Short
  FROM YourTable t
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT YEAR(t.MaturityDate)) x (Year)
  INNER JOIN numbers y ON y.Number BETWEEN YEAR(GETDATE()) AND x.Year
  CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      Long  = CASE y.Number WHEN x.Year THEN t.Long  ELSE 0 END,
      Short = CASE y.Number WHEN x.Year THEN t.Short ELSE 0 END
  ) z (Long, Short)
),
pivoted AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM unfolded
  PIVOT (
    SUM(YearValue) FOR Year IN ([2013], [2014], [2015], [2016], [2017], [2018], [2019], [2020],
                [2021], [2022], [2023], [2024], [2025], [2026], [2027], [2028], [2029], [2030],
                [2031], [2032], [2033], [2034], [2035], [2036], [2037], [2038], [2039], [2040])
  ) p
)
SELECT *
FROM pivoted
;
```

It returns results for a static range years. To use it for a dynamically calculated year range, you'll first need to prepare the list of years as a CSV string, something like this:

```
SET @columnlist = STUFF(
  (
    SELECT  ', [' + CAST(Number) + ']'
    FROM numbers
    WHERE Number BETWEEN YEAR(GETDATE())
                     AND (SELECT YEAR(MAX(MaturityDate)) FROM YourTable)
    ORDER BY Number
  FOR XML PATH ('')
  ),
  1, 2, ''
);
```

then put it into the dynamic SQL version of the query:

```
SET @sql = N'
WITH unfolded AS (
...
  PIVOT (
    SUM(YearValue) FOR Year IN (' + @columnlist + ')
  ) p
)
SELECT *
FROM pivoted;
';
```

and execute the result:

```
EXECUTE(@sql);
```

You can try this solution [at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eadc3/8).